# Codeigniter _remap function

Tags: url, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Please help I want to use first URI segment into my CodeIgniter website.

Like when I open these url they opens my profile: 
http://www.facebook.com/buddyforever 
or 
http://www.myspace.com/zarpio

How can I do this with CodeIgniter? I checked `_remap` function but first coming controller how to hide controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using the URL routing of codeigniter...

If you want your URL to be `http://www.mydomain.com/zarpio` and you want it to refer to `your_controller`, then do the following.

/config/routes.php

```
$route['(.*)'] = "your_controller/$1"; // Now, `zarpio` will be passed to `your_controller`
```

You can access it in your controller like this...

```
$my_name = $this->uri->rsegment(2);
```

However I do not suggest this way of configuring URLs. A better way would be...

```
$route['users/(.*)'] = "your_controller/$1";
```

This way, you're just renaming your controller name `your_controller` to `users`.

If you want to access profile of a user, you can do it like this...

```
$route['users/profile/(.*)'] = "another_controller/method/$1";
$route['users/(.*)'] = "your_controller/$1";
```

Consider the order of routing. Since you wrote `users/(.*)` in your route, it will match `users/zarpio` as well as `users/profile/zarpio`, and route both of them to `your_controller/$1`, which in the case of profile will give you a `404 page not found` error. That is why you need to write `users/profile/(.*)` before `users/(.*)` in your routing configuration.

More information in [codeigniter URI class documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

Comment: Please, Can you give me full tutorial?

Comment: Thank you ShiVik I did it. You are genius

Comment: @ShiVik Can you please solve my another problem? I am using $route['(.*)'] = "your_controller/$1"; into my routes.php now problem is that when I goto www.mydomain.com/myanothercontroller/method... 404 Page Not Found comes... is there anything else to do in config/routes.php file?

Comment: Thanks - this helped. I have to route all my modules above the user module though.