# Codeigniter: I would like create user URL's for my users when they create a username

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I wold like to create this kind of URL for my users when they register a username
mysite.com/username

I've search many posts on this site and I see people doing it like this mysite.com/user/username

I would like to get rid of the user and just have it go directly to mysite.com/username

What would be the best way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with CodeIgniter but here is a general answer for why people don't use mysite.com/username:

mysite.com/user/username is a good solution because usually the URL dispatcher passes username to a function/module that handles users' page.

mysite.com/username is a bad solution because your dispatcher will have to have a greedy rule  after all your other rules, to pass everything other that those previous rules to the module/function that handles users' page.

Now suppose you want to use mysite.com/username and suppose you have mysite.com/logout which lands users to the logout page. A user comes and registers himself with "logout" as his username. Then how are you going to say by accessing mysite.com/logout Mr. logout wants to logout or wants to see his page?

Comment: I get you totally. There must be a solution, my site was built using raw php before I lost it all and that is the way the profiles were accessed, but I never had problems. Hmm not sure how to get around this one.

Comment: What if I reserved names that can't be registered? By the way users register with their first and last name email address, password sex and date of birth. The username option becomes available once they're in their member area and they can choose one instantly and assigned to their account.

Comment: If you really want mysite.com/username , then this solution will work for you. As you said even if you don't reserve the names the chances of someone creating a strange username is slim. But I still insist that it's not the best practice.

Answer (score 5):

You could look into routes:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

You enter routes into config/routes.php

As an example:

```
$route['([a-zA-Z]+)'] = "main_controller/user_function/$1";
```

But as @Nylon Smile said above, if you attempt to use logout, it will try to access logouts' user page.

Comment: I see exactly what Nylon is saying so what if I used mysite.com/user/username wouldn't there be a way to change the URL route so it displays mysite.com/username and user can type that in to get to their profile page?

Comment: I'm thinking this is doing exactly what I'm asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614705/codeigniter-remap-function correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty much the same thing. The way I have it though, it will make sure to only pick up the first segment as it only accepts alphabetical characters. No symbols. You could always add numbers as well. It depends on your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding an item to the $route array in 'config/routes.php':

```
$route['([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = "user/index/$1";
```

This maps example.com/whatever to to the 'index' function of the 'user' controller.

Yes, there will be collisions if you have a 'logout' controller and a user named 'logout'. You can solve this by putting adding the following item to the $route array *before* the one above:

```
$route['logout'] = "logout";
```

And keeping a blacklist of usernames that includes your controllers. This will take some upkeep, so you may want to go with the other solutions listed here that prefix something like 'user/' in the URL before their username and avoid all that.

Comment: What about using logout as a subdomain e.g. logout.mystie.com

Comment: A subdomain for each controller seems like a big hassle.