# create a dynamic url in codeigniter like facebook

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to create a dynamic url in codeigniter like the facebook application. Is it possible to create such url using the codeigniter framework?
eg:
1.  www.facebook.com/nisha
2.  www.facebook.com/dev

Comment: You might be looking for Apache's [mod_rewrite](https://www.google.com/search?q=mod+rewrite+tutorial).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter: I would like create user URL's for my users when they create a username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632857/codeigniter-i-would-like-create-user-urls-for-my-users-when-they-create-a-user)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up custom routing for the controller in application/config/routes.php. Like:

```
$route['([a-zA-Z]+)'] = "controller_name/function/$1";
```

This makes urls like the way you want, but it makes all of your controller inaccessible, that is because any '**/controllername/parameter/**' format will match with '**(:any)**' and will be redirected to our '**controller_name/function/**'.

To stop controllers redirected by the CI router, you will have to explicitly define all of your controllers on the routes.php first then add the above mentioned routing rule at last line. Thats how i made it to work.
Hope that helps you in some way.

Comment: This will also match `domain.com/1234123`

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy to setup this by the use of routes. Read their routing [guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

```
$route['([a-zA-Z]+)'] = "controller/user/$1";
```

However, if their is only one way of accessing the website, is like `domain.com/username` then its ok, otherwise, this will prove be a hard catch on the long run. On that case, limit the Route to a limited scope like

```
$route['users/([a-zA-Z]+)'] = "controller/user/$1";
```

This will help in the extending the system in numerous way

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. it will reduce a lot of repetitive line if you have lots of controller but i don't know does it violate any CI rules.

```
//this code block should be placed after any kind of reserved routes config
$url_parts = explode('/',strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) );
$reserved_routes = array("controller_1", "controller_2", "controller_3" );
if (!in_array($url_parts[1], $reserved_routes)) {    
    $route['([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = "controller_1/profile/$1";
}
```