# clean 'twitter like' urls using codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

hello am building a site and would need people to be able to access there webpages using a urkl such as www.example.com/username , i was able to implement a solution using the route (:any) feature ,but i encountered two problems :::
1.i have to implement the route to all the pages on the website.
2.user avatars where no longer showing because instead of pointing to the images directly by following the directory path i usually call the images with a function in the controller

so i was wondering if there was a way to go about this using a .htaccess file while eliminating index.php in the proccess ... thank you

Comment: You need to use a htaccess RewriteRule. Please go back and accept your previous answers first though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at mod_rewrite (for your webserver; like Apache). This module can rewrite pretty url's to your website structure, thus presenting nice url's and have your site behave normal.

Comment: although in code igniters case you have just as much control over the url's in the routing class as you do in the .htaccess, the best bet would be to define your controller's as seperate routes, then have the any route as the last route as I am pretty sure code igniter stops once it meets a route that matches it, I would show an example, but well, the OP does not seem to recognize people for their help (0% accept)

Answer (score 0):

[ShiVik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206613/shivik) posted a pretty thorough answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614705/codeigniter-remap-function/3615064#3615064). I'm about try it out.