# what is the use of _remap in codeIgniter using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hi frnds can anyone explain me what is the use of **_remap** function in codeIgniter using PHP with example and description clearly please...

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614705/codeigniter-remap-function#answer-3615064) and see if it helps.

Comment: Read this http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/codeigniter-remap-power-benefit.html

Answer (score 8):

see [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls)

**Remapping Function Calls**

If your controller contains a function named _remap(), it will always get called regardless of what your URI contains. It overrides the normal behavior in which the URI determines which function is called, allowing you to define your own function routing rules.

For example:
your url is `localhost/index.php/user/index` and you don't want to call `index` for this then you can use `_remap()` to map new function `view` instead of `index` like this.

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method == 'index')
    {
        $this->view();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->default_method();
    }
}
```

Comment: i already seen this above link.after that also i can't able to understand.plz explain me in a easy way

Answer (score 0):

In this short code we should have to pass index in url to display what we echoed. But with _remap() inside of the function itself. We should have to pass the indexs instead of index. Let's say you have a lot of function and you just named it public function codeig(){} and it's a shame to pass the codeig inside the url, right?. So you are going to use the _remap and make the codeig as hello or any (function name you want) and you are now able to pass hello or what you named to your function to url.

```
class Tuts extends CI_Controller{
    public function index($name = 'john',$age=18){
        echo "Your name is $name, you are $age years old";
    }

    public function _remap($method){
        if ($method === 'indexs') { //you should have to type indexs in uri instead of index
            $this->index();
        }else{
            $this->default_method();
        }
    }
```